# How to avoid duplicate content with Symfony and locale routes?

Tags: http, symfony, annotations, routes

I'm having trouble with locale routes in symfony 2.5.
Let's say my default language ist english. My example route is /user/register/. If I request it without any locale it should appear the english translation. If I request it with a locale (e.g. /fr/user/register/) it should appear with it. This can be done with the following:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}/user/register/")
 * @Route("/user/register/")
 * @Template()
 */
public function registerAction(Request $request)
{
    $locale = $request->getLocale();
    $translated = $this->get('translator')->trans('test.output');

    echo $locale."<br>".$translated;
    exit();
}
```

Now I have to questions to this:

- How can I simply avoid that a user can call the route with the default language as a locale? In my example english is the default language, so /en/user/register/ would have the same output as /user/register/. I don't want to make a 301-redirect in each controller-action!
- Is there no simple way to annotate a route with and without locale with one route-annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know for the fact that this can be achieved via [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle). Not only that, but you could use case such as:

```
/contact       # For English language
/de/kontakt    # For German
```

Comment: Can you please post an example of the usage for my use case? I didn't found this in the documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong library link (from the same dev) :) It's fixed now :)

Comment: Although, I must state the obvious: Johannes Schmitt really does poor job when it comes to documenting his bundles.. :(

Comment: Well, I don't get it to run: `Invalid configuration at path "jms_i18n_routing.default_locale": The default locale must be one of the configured locales`. This happens because I didn't defined the locales. I don't want to limit the languages because this is part of my controller. So this bundle unfortunately this bundle is not helpful for me. It should only check if it's the default language and if so, redirect to it without the local in the route.

Comment: well, at some point I think you will have to "limit the languages", right?

Comment: Well, I have to think about that. I thought there would be an option to avoid duplicate content without limiting the languages. I mean, all informations for my requirements are the default language and nothing.

Comment: Also, if you want to build a bundle on the most applications, you can't require thirdparty plugins

Answer (score 1):

You can add requirements for the routes, for example:

```
 * @Route("/{_locale}/user/register/", requirements={"_locale" = "fr|it"})
```

And with this, only those options, what are listed there can be placed into the _locale placeholder

EDIT:

I understand now your problem. Then here is the solution for you:
[JsmI18n](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/master/configuration#scenario-prefixing-all-routes-with-the-locale-except-those-of-the-default-locale)

Comment: Thanks that would be helpful if I have another use case. But I want to use the action in the default language without any locale in the route. So /fr/user/register/ would be invalid if it's the default language. Instead this must be redirect to /user/register/. But as I said, it's redundant to make this 301-redirect in each action. So what would be a better option to realize it?